# How to mock function with generic type using mocked ts-jest/utils

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I have a function like this

```
const myOtherMethod = (param1: any) => {
  // return some code
}

export const myFunc = <T>(param1: any): T => {
  const value: T = myOtherMethod(param1);
  return value;
}
```

and I want to mock the `myFunc` function
I try like this

```
mocked(myFunc as string)
```

or like this

```
mocked<string>(myFunc)
```

but not work. Any idea about this?

Comment: Can you provide the code of `myOtherMethod` function?

Comment: @slideshowp2, done, But the point of interest not the myOtheMethod